# CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Tags: hibernate, cascade

I have an User entity with a ManyToOne relation with Address

```
@NotNull
@ManyToOne
@Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_registered_address")
private Address registeredAddress;
```

When I set to 'registeredAddress' an address from db (dao.getById) and then call saveOrUpdate on my User entity I get:

```
A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session
```

If I set a new created Address entity, this entity is correctly saved in db.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This means that hibernate finds 2 addresses or more in the session and it doesn't know which one to use when updating address. May be you fetch the same address twice.

Comment: In fact, I was fetching twice

Comment: Glade it works. Good luck.

Comment: @BilalBBB I'm closing old questions, maybe you want to add an answer in order to be accepted

Comment: Thank you I added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that hibernate finds 2 addresses or more in the session and it doesn't know which one to use when updating address. May be you fetch the same address twice.